# Why is my previously working xml button not triggering?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, user-interface, xamarin

I am building a Xamarin app with two icons in which I have used the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gas_Sense;assembly=Gas_Sense"
             x:Class="Gas_Sense.HomePage"
             Title="Home Page">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="7, 40, 7, 10" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>           
        <Button x:Name="NewDeviceButton" Image="add.png" 
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                BackgroundColor="aqua"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I thought this should put the button in the bottom Right hand corner of my screen. Instead it has done this:

[image: Screenshot]

The button sits inside a grid layout on a content page. Why is the button sitting in the middle of its grid? The icon doens't have any whitespace around it.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/6540266a2ae6beb8de1e) of the full code.

Would be grateful for any ideas, as I am not having much luck...

## EDIT:

I have now changed the code, such that the plus icon is now in it's own column, which has a defined width and height, see below:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The button is now defined as:

```
<Button x:Name="NewDeviceButton" Image="add.png" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" />
```

The button is attached to the following C# code:

```
NewDeviceButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {

    devices.Clear();
    adapter.StartScanningForDevices (0x180D.UuidFromPartial ());
}
```

It looks fine! However, I can't click it? Why would this be, I have only changed the location definitions, but now no matter how much I click on or around the button, it won't trigger. Any ideas what is wrong with it?

Comment: Is the problem that the button isn't aligned, or that the image inside of the button isn't right-aligned?

Comment: @Jason The button with an image property is in the middle of it's grid cell, and I would like it on the right hand side (the plus sign in the picture)

Comment: The xaml for the button does not have an onclick or command handler attached?

Comment: @ClintLandry It does, it is just in the accompanying C#, I'll add it to the question

Comment: I am a little confused. Perhaps I have just not coded in that particular architecture but in order to attach a xaml defined button to an event handler I think you need to define it in xaml. If the button is defined in code behind sure add a lambda, delegate or whatever in code behind but if it is defined in xaml i believe you need to add the event handler relationship in xaml as well. I would guess that your xaml newdevicebutton and your code behind new device button are not pointing to the same object.

Comment: @ClintLandry I think it may just be that we are using different architectures, in Xamarin, you can use this setup, the button did indeed work with the code I wrote before the edit, it is only since the redefinition of the columns and button positioning, that it has stopped working